# ANT: Define a variable and execute another task

Tags: java, xml, ant, build

I tried the following in ant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="real" basedir=".">
  <target name="task">
    <mkdir dir="${value}" />
  </target>
  <target name="real" depends="task">
    <property name="value" value="real" />
  </target>
  <target name="fake" depends="task">
    <property name="value" value="fake" />
  </target>
</project>
```

But it didn't work as I expected: the property is defined **after** the task is executed.

How can I define a variable in a task, and then call another task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both the `real` and `fake` tasks depend on `task`, it means that `task` is executed first. That's how ant resolves task dependencies.

You could look at the [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task to call another target after setting a variable.